# OpenVPN /21 subnet

Tags: openvpn

We have powerful servers to handle ~2000 simultaneous connections so if we set OpenVPN subnet to `10.8.0.0/21 (255.255.248.0)` and `max_clients 2046` and adjust the firewall accordingly, it should work. Right?

Comment: if you have such enough computing power it might work, but remind that 0 and 255 are not usable on each subnet

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Comment: @vidarlo How my question is related to that?